Understanding the geometry behind finding the area of a triangle defined by three vertices in three space
I am self-studying linear algebra using Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra textbook (published in 2020). As I was making my way through the determinants section, I stumbled upon the following question:

The solution provided is this:

I have several questions about the following solution. First, I understand the reasoning behind subtracting two vectors from the third. In doing so, we represent the two vectors in their canonical form, which will make it possible to apply determinant reasoning later on. From there, however, I get confused. The solution indicates that we need to find an orthogonal vector (with respect to the two vectors computed above) of length one. Why length one and why orthogonal? From there, we take the determinant of the matrix formed by this orthogonal vector and the two vectors computed earlier. Using my geometric understanding, the absolute value of the determinant of this matrix represents the volume of the parallelepid formed by the three vectors. Why, then, is one-half the volume of this parallelepiped the area of the triangle? Dividing by a unitless one-half should not lead to a loss of dimension. I have scrambled over the internet for a sound explanation and cannot find one.
Would someone be able to help point me in the direction of why we are finding this particular orthogonal vector, and the geometric interpretation of one-half this particular determinant?

What you really want is half the area of the 2-d parallelogram spanned by these two vectors. Computing areas is a bit trickier in 3 dimensions, but volumes are much more sensible. The area of the 2-d parallelogram you want is exactly the same as the volume of the 3-d parallelepiped spanned by the original two vectors and a unit vector which is orthogonal to the original two vectors (verify this). The reason this is easier is we already have a very easy way of finding this volume - the determinant.

The key here is to interpret the parallelopiped formed by these vectors as a parallelogram prism. Take the parallelogram shape formed by $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(2, -3, 3)$ as the base, and the unit perpendicular vector to be the height. The volume of a prism is the area of the base multiplied by the height, so the fact that vector is unit length means that the unit of the parallelopiped will equal the area of the parallelogram. Halving this quantity gives the area of the triangle.

Since the third vector is perpendicular to the plane and has length $1$, the parallellopiped formed by the 3 vectors is a straight cylinder and its volume is $1$ times the area of the base parallellogram. Hence half the volume is the area of the triangle.
The units: you divide by the side length $1$ which has units.
